# Trying to force update_dyld_shared_cache but having some errors

Tags: macos, dynamic-library

I am trying to force the update of my dyld shared cache using the command

```
sudo update_dyld_shared_cache -root / -force
```

But after a while I see a bunch of errors like this, related to `spindump`:

> update_dyld_shared_cache[719] : Unable to unlink //var/db/spindump/OLDDSC-E2D77243-3FD9-32E5-AE64-3506904D5579: 1 Operation not permitted

How do I fix this?

I am on El Capitan.

Comment: Those errors are logged for all updates - it's the old code fighting against SIP, but in practice, they seem harmless. Are you really looking to suppress the warnings or is there some failure relating to them you are trying to address?

Comment: So what is this task actually? it's using over 5Gb or memory on my machine, but couldn't figure out what this task is doing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What fixed it for me was

```
update_dyld_shared_cache -debug
```

This is what you should see

```
update_dyld_shared_cache: adding root: /System/Library/...
...
...
update_dyld_shared_cache: /var/db/dyld/dyld_shared_cache_i386 is up-to-date
update_dyld_shared_cache: /var/db/dyld/dyld_shared_cache_x86_64 is up-to-date
```

to be sure it works I run

```
update_dyld_shared_cache
```

a second time

Answer (score 3):

Reboot your mac in recovery mode (https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201314),
Open Terminal there and type

```
rm -rf /Volumes/<your_system_volume>var/db/spindump/*
```

After that restart your mac and repeat the operation

```
sudo update_dyld_shared_cache -root / -force
```

PS see detailed comment from @CharlieMonroe

Comment: several things happened when I tried your commands. 1. I was denied the removal of spindump files with the message **sandbox: system police deny file write unlinke... bla bla**... yes, I am administrator and I have root access.  Trying the second command would give me the same errors. I still have the same files and I am still unable to update_dylid_shared_cache.

Comment: The answer is almost right, but: `/` refers to the recovery volume, which is AFAIK read-only (it creates various RAM disks for RW stuff). Which is why the command fails, since you are trying to remove files from the recovery volume. The corrected command should look like this: `rm -rf /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/var/db/spindump/*`, `Macintosh\ HD` being an escaped name of your start-up drive.

Comment: @CharlieMonroe you are right. I missed that thing in the path

Comment: Aren't these files protected/restricted by SIP so efforts to remove them fail in recovery mode as they do when `update_dyld_shared_cache` tries to delete them?

Comment: If your main volume has FileVault 2 enabled, you'll need to unlock it before you can access it in recovery mode. To do this, open Disk Utility, select the volume, and choose "Unlock" from Disk Utility's File menu. Once unlocked, it can be accessed until the next reboot.

Answer (score 1):

the -debug flag on update_dyld_shared_cache doesn't do anything except provide more detail on the work that is being done -- that is makes the reporting more verbose.

I'd use: sudo update_dyld_shared_cache -root / -force

All systems provide 'errors' though these aren't issues, rather information on what can't be done or skipped because the way the module is implimented.

These are the typical 'errors' for a heathly system:

update_dyld_shared_cache: warning: x86_64h skipping because of bad install name /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/fcl-fc-1.dat
update_dyld_shared_cache: warning: x86_64h skipping because of bad install name /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/fcl-fc-2.dat
update_dyld_shared_cache: warning: x86_64h skipping because of bad install name /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/fcl-fc-3.dat
update_dyld_shared_cache: warning: i386 skipping because of bad install name /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/fcl-fc-1.dat
update_dyld_shared_cache: warning: i386 skipping because of bad install name /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/fcl-fc-2.dat
update_dyld_shared_cache: warning: i386 skipping because of bad install name /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/fcl-fc-3.dat
update_dyld_shared_cache: warning: x86_64h rejected from cached dylibs: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CreateML.framework/Versions/A/CreateML (("Could not find dependency '/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TuriCore.framework/Versions/A/TuriCore'"))
update_dyld_shared_cache: warning: x86_64h rejected from cached dylibs: /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCreateML.dylib (("Could not find dependency '/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TuriCore.framework/Versions/A/TuriCore'"))
bash-3.2$ sudo update_dyld_shared_cache -root -force
update_dyld_shared_cache: error: could not stat root file system because 'No such file or directory'
bash-3.2$ sudo update_dyld_shared_cache -root / -force
update_dyld_shared_cache: warning: x86_64h skipping because of bad install name /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/fcl-fc-1.dat
update_dyld_shared_cache: warning: x86_64h skipping because of bad install name /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/fcl-fc-2.dat
update_dyld_shared_cache: warning: x86_64h skipping because of bad install name /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/fcl-fc-3.dat
update_dyld_shared_cache: warning: i386 skipping because of bad install name /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/fcl-fc-1.dat
update_dyld_shared_cache: warning: i386 skipping because of bad install name /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/fcl-fc-2.dat
update_dyld_shared_cache: warning: i386 skipping because of bad install name /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/fcl-fc-3.dat
update_dyld_shared_cache: i386 incorporating 629 OS dylibs, tracking 456 others, building closures for 243 executables
update_dyld_shared_cache: warning: x86_64h rejected from cached dylibs: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CreateML.framework/Versions/A/CreateML (("Could not find dependency '/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TuriCore.framework/Versions/A/TuriCore'"))
update_dyld_shared_cache: warning: x86_64h rejected from cached dylibs: /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCreateML.dylib (("Could not find dependency '/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TuriCore.framework/Versions/A/TuriCore'"))